# Node + express session data

Tags: node.js, mongodb, session, express

I'm working with this boilderplate https://github.com/sahat/hackathon-starter, which is using express-session, mongostore, for user session management.

The node document created for each session looks like this:

```
{
    "_id": "QDKVO5GM6GrNYd0SlQyTgJsx",
    "session": "{\"cookie\":{\"originalMaxAge\":null,\"expires\":null,\"httpOnly\":true,\"path\":\"/\"},\"passport\":{\"user\":\"535e005c02d3c0ed79463583\"},\"_csrfSecret\":\"MqLJJ8qZLSk5/w==\",\"returnTo\":\"/\",\"flash\":{}}",
    "expires": {
    "$date": "2014-05-12T08:27:04.696Z"
    }
}
```

Is there a way that I can add data to each session?  The goal here is to use the session data to store products in a cart.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add properties, and therefore data, to the session variable in the same way that you can to any Javascript object.

If you're using `express-session` then you have access to the `req.session` variable so you can store a data object using

```
req.session.data = data;
```

and it will be available as long as the session remains alive.

Comment: Nice I'll give this a try!  Thanks for the response JuJo

Answer (score 0):

Just attach objects/values to your `req.session` object and they will be saved at the end of the response.